# Different font Textsizes for different devices in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I want to use the same text on different iPhone devices. I am using the universal storyboard but I can't find any constraints for the font size.

Can any one help me how to change text sizes as per device? Like in iPhone 5s device the label text size was 15 then I need text size on iPhone 6sPlus Should be at least 17.

Comment: You can take reference from storyboard to controller and can set different font sizes to the label/textField/textView programatically comparing device.

Comment: you need to use size classes and check "Trait variations" and "Auto Layput" in your storyboard.

Comment: Check this link https://www.raywenderlich.com/162311/adaptive-layout-tutorial-ios-11-getting-started